# Why do I get different results only 1% of the time?

Tags: c, casting, int, double, formula

I am trying to truncate everything past the hundredths decimal. (13.4396 would be 13.43) Sholdn't it always or never work?

I have this formula that works 99%:

```
    input = (( (double) ((int)(orgInput * 100)) )  / 100) ;
```

Then I have this formula sequence that is arithmetically equivalent:

```
    input = (orgInput * 100);
    input = (int) input;
    input = (double) (input);
    input = input / 100;
```

These inputs do not give the desired result (Formula truncates and round down, while the broken down steps output the desired result):

12.33

99.99

22.22

44.32

56.78

11.11

And then an even bigger mystery to me is why 33.30 does not work on either of them. Below is my program that runs continuously to demonstrate my problem.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(void)
    {
        double orgInput, input;
        while (4!=3)
        {
            printf("Please enter the dollar amount (up to $100)  => ");
           scanf("%lf", &orgInput);

            /* Truncates anything past hundredths place */
            input = (orgInput * 100) ;
            printf("\n1. input is %g \n ", input);

            input = (int) input ;
            printf("\n2. input is %g \n ", input);

            input = (double) (input)   ;
            printf("\n3. input is %g \n", input);

            input = input / 100 ;
            printf("\n4. input is %.2lf \n", input);

            input = (( (double) ((int)(orgInput * 100)) )  / 100) ;
            printf("\nUsing the formula the input is %.2lf \n \n\n", input);

        }
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }
```

Thank you in advance!!!!   P.S. Sorry for the formatting I am still getting used to stackoverflow

Key phrases:
Double to int conversion
Precision error

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: See [The Floating-Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand that floats are represented in binary as:

> 2^(exponent) * mantissa

Exponent is a standard integer, but mantissa (a value between 1 and 2) is a number of bits where each bit represents a fraction: 1, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16 and so on... Therefore it is not possible for the mantissa to represent certain values exactly, it will have an accuracy of +/- some fraction.

For example you mentioned 33.30. As a float 33.30 can only be: 2^5 * mantissa.

In this case the mantissa has to be 33.30/32 = 1.40625 exactly. But by making it out of the fractions the closest it can be is be is: 1.0406249999999999111821580299874767661094. So the actual value of the double is not 33.30, its 33.2999999999999971578290569595992565155029296875, which of course rounds DOWN to 33.29 when you do the type cast to integer.

The correct way to fix your program is not to scan in a float in the first place. You should be scanning in two integers seperated by decimal, and if scanf returns a value that indicates it did not scan two integers, then scan it as one integer for the case of a dollar only value.

Sadly, printf works by conversions to ints inside it and will not properly print any double precision floats that have more than 6 decimal places, which is why you see it as 33.30 even through you are asking printf to print the value of a double.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are suffering from floating-point precision errors.

You should be able to fix this by doing:

```
const double epsilon = 1e-10;  // Or some suitable small number
input = floor(orgInput * 100 + epsilon) / 100;
```

An alternative is to stop this from happening on input.  Instead of reading in a double, you read a string and then parse that to get out the dollar and cents amount (cents being exactly 2 digits following the decimal point, if any).  You can then ignore everything else.

In general, if you are working with money truncated to cents, you might be best to keep it in cents and use integers.  Either that or round instead of truncate (for my above example, that would mean an epsilon of 0.5).

Comment: The code really helped me to understand where the error was. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Most machines use binary, not decimal floating point. While binary-to-decimal conversion always gives exact values (in theory), it's impossible to convert from decimal to binary without rounding (I'm not considering the impractical case when numbers can have infinite number of digits).

As such, all your binary floating-point numbers are going to be slightly off of what they would've been in decimal.

The only 1-digit decimal fractions that can be represented in binary are: .0, .5.

Likewise, 2-digit decimal fractions exactly representable in binary are: .00, .25, .50, .75 (see [here](http://ideone.com/Hk4SM)).

If you want, which I doubt, you can round to the nearest fraction of the four.